# Qt event when widget goes out of sight

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way in Qt to handle situation when any widget of Window goes out of sight. I.e if a widget was in tab control and user have changed active tab, or if user just scrolls and widget goes offscreen, and also when it goes back on screen.

Is that possible to add some code to this two events?

Best if this can be done globally...

Comment: As I understand it, this is a non-trivial task. Events do not give real information about whether a target widget is *really* visible at the moment. The [QWidget::isVisible()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#visible-prop) method also does not give the information. Seems like the issue requires non-trivial combination of events handling like [**Paint Event**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintevent.html) - it should not be emitted while widget is not really visible. See also [QWidget::mapToGlobal()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mapToGlobal)

Comment: The tab is "easy" as a QTabWidget should show and hide widgets. The scroll one is not; it depends on the geometry (position and size) of the complete widget hierarchy going from your widget to the top level, as widgets clip their children. A change of geometry anywhere in the hierarchy will need to update this visibility information. That sounds expensive to do for 99.999999% of widgets which don't care.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way in Qt to handle situation when any widget of Window goes out of sight. I.e if a widget was in tab control and user have changed active tab, or if user just scrolls and widget goes offscreen, and also when it goes back on screen.

The way the question asked makes one think that the widget show-hide-expose state changes need to be handled:

```
bool MyWidget::event(QEvent* pEvent)
{
    if (pEvent->type() == QEvent::Show)
    {
      // event "shown"
    }
    else if (pEvent->type() == QEvent::Hide)
    {
      // event "hidden"
    }
    else if (pEvent->type() == QEvent::Expose)
    {
      // event "exposure changed"
      // deal with QExposeEvent and evaluate the exposed region
      // QExposeEvent* pExposeEvent = reinterpret_cast<QExposeEvent*>(pEvent);
    }
    return QWidget::event(pEvent);
}
```

> Best if this can be done globally...

Event filter at the top level widget may solve that. Or you can override [event()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#event) function for the top level widget but finding what exact widget was affected is another thing.

Refer to QExposeEvent [description](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qexposeevent.html).